# RSS feed scraping with Python

Tags: python, regex, rss, screen-scraping

I'm a newbie to Python and programming in general so please excuse me if the question is very dumb.

I've been following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap_DlSrT-iE&list=PLA175E8A1816CD64B&index=13&feature=plpp_video) tutorial on RSS scraping step by step but I am getting a "list index out of range" error from Python when trying to gather the corresponding links to the titles of the articles being gathered.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

source  = urlopen('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/raw_feed').read()

title = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
link = re.compile('<link>(.*)</link>')

find_title = re.findall(title, source)
find_link = re.findall(link, source)

literate = []
literate[:] = range(1, 16)

for i in literate:
    print find_title[i]
    print find_link[i]
```

It executes fine when I only tell it to retrieve titles, but immediately throws an index error when I would like to retrieve titles **and** their corresponding links.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a wrong regex for extracting link from your page.

```
>>> link = re.compile('<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href=(.*)')
>>> find_link = re.findall(link, source)
>>> find_link[1].strip()
'"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/andrew-brandt/the-peyton-predicament-pa_b_1271834.html" />'
>>> len(find_link)
15
>>>
```

Take a  look at `html source` of your page you will find that the links are not enclosed in
`<link></link>` pattern.

Actually the pattern is `<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href= links here`.

That's the reason why your regex is not working.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`feedparser` module to parse an RSS feed from a given url](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/introduction.html#parsing-a-feed-from-a-remote-url):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import feedparser # pip install feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/latestnews')
# .. skipped handling http errors, cacheing ..

for e in d.entries:
    print(e.title)
    print(e.link)
    print(e.description)
    print("\n") # 2 newlines
```

#### Output

```
Even Critics Of Safety Net Increasingly Depend On It
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/02/12/safety-net-benefits_n_1271867.html
<p>Ki Gulbranson owns a logo apparel shop, deals in 
<!-- ... snip ... -->

Christopher Cain, Atlanta Anti-Gay Attack Suspect, Arrested And
Charged With Aggravated Assault And Robbery
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/02/12/atlanta-anti-gay-suspect-christopher-cain-arrested_n_1271811.html
<p>ATLANTA -- Atlanta police have arrested a suspect 
<!-- ... snip ... -->
```

It might not be a good idea to use [regular expressions to parse rss(xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).